# Erewhon font doesn't work in cyrillic

Tags: fonts, babel, cyrillic

I'm working on my LaTeX project (I'm using MikTeX on Win10, pdflatex). I need to use Serbian cyrillic (babel, **serbianc**) script. I found this new **erewhon** font, whose documentation says it can be used with T2A encoding.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work, for unknown reasons. This is simple piece of code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,oneside,a4paper,titlepage,draft]{article}

% set serbianc...
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtext}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,serbianc]{babel}

% load erewhon, as in erewhon manual..
\usepackage[p,osf,scaled=.98,space]{erewhon}
\usepackage[varqu,varl]{inconsolata} % typewriter
\usepackage[type1,scaled=.95]{cabin} % sans serif like Gill Sans
\usepackage[utopia,vvarbb]{newtxmath}

%change some names..
\addto\captionsserbianc{
    \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Садржаније}
}

\begin{document}

% toc...
\tableofcontents

%main text...
\section[Поглавље]{Поглавље}
Текст у поглављу.
\subsection[Подпоглавље]{Подпоглавље}
Текст у подпоглављу.
\subsubsection[Минипоглавље]{Минипоглавље}
Текст у минипоглављу.
\paragraph[Параграф]{Параграф}
Текст у параграфу.

\end{document}
```

edit: The first compilation error I get:

```
LaTeX Error: Symbol font `LY1letters' is not defined.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Just curious: It's 2017 and we have Unicode-capable engine (LuaTeX & XeTeX) which can handle Opentype fonts. Why don't you use them?

Comment: "it doesn't work" - meaning what exactly? Does the computer explode?

Comment: @MartinSchröder I'll definitely try using XeTeX, if there isn't other solution. (the first) compilation error will be added to the post.

Comment: If I remove `mathtext` and postpone loading babel after the font packages, I get no error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package `mathtext` (which I don't really understand the purpose of) is the cause. You should also postpone loading `babel` after the font packages.

```
\documentclass[10pt,oneside,a4paper,titlepage,draft]{article}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,textcomp}

% load erewhon, as in erewhon manual..
\usepackage[erewhon,vvarbb]{newtxmath}
\usepackage[p,osf,scaled=.98,space]{erewhon}
\usepackage[varqu,varl]{inconsolata} % typewriter
\usepackage[type1,scaled=.95]{cabin} % sans serif like Gill Sans

% set serbianc...
\usepackage[english,serbianc]{babel}

%change some names..
\addto\captionsserbianc{%
    \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Садржаније}%
}

\begin{document}

% toc...
\tableofcontents

%main text...
\section[Поглавље]{Поглавље}
Текст у поглављу.
\subsection[Подпоглавље]{Подпоглавље}
Текст у подпоглављу.
\subsubsection[Минипоглавље]{Минипоглавље}
Текст у минипоглављу.
\paragraph[Параграф]{Параграф}
Текст у параграфу.
\[
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\int_{k-1}^{k} f(x)\,dx=\int_{0}^{n}f(x)\,dx
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]